# Rails Bundler - specify with-opt-dir in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, puma

I am able to install puma after downloading openssl and executing the following command:

```
gem install -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
```

The problem is then if I try to update puma with bundle, it knows nothing of this directory.

Can you specify `-- --with-opt-dir=` in a Rails Gemfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify this in bundle config as follows: `bundle config build.puma --with-opt-dir=your/opt/dir` and bundler will pass it to the gem install.